# Bootstrap 3 carousel not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My slider isn't sliding and when I click on any buttons to change image it does not work. I am guessing this is something to with jQuery or the bootstrap.js file. Here is my HTML code

```
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="party.png" alt="Slide 1">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="party2.png" alt="Slide 2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

At the bottom of my page I have the JavaScript files. They look like this.

```
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I checked and the file paths are correct. Btw I am using Electron and not a plain browser. I don't think it makes a difference but just keep it in mind. Thanks! ;)

Comment: are you calling the jquery file before the bootstrap js file? that is an important part to making it work.

Comment: This code will not give us clear idea about what is going wrong, at this moment we can only guess what is going wrong. If you can show entire us code, then it might help us to find the solution.

Comment: Errors in the browser console?